# Prevent A User From Downloading Files from Python?

Tags: python, windows, passwords, download

I am working on a project that requires password protected downloading, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement that. If the target file has a specific extension (.exe, .mp3, .mp4, etc), I want to prompt the user for a username and password. Any ideas on this?

I am using Python 26 on Windows XP.

Comment: "password protected downloading" from what?  An FTP server?  Done -- FTP already does that.  What kind of "downloading" are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about downloading in general! When a user open a browser, cliks on a link to download a file, I want to prompt for a password. From what? EVERYTHING!

Comment: There is no "downloading in general".  If you're talking about a "browser", then perhaps you're really taking about downloading **from a web site**, which means **from a web-based application**.  Please update your question to say "download **from a web server** ".

Comment: I am not understanding how you have come to the conclusion that there is no such thing as "downloading in general". There is. It is downloading of any file that does not open in the browser. If it is not clear what I am talking about, how is it that Alex Martelli was able to provide a usable solution?

Comment: Because you're talking about downloading a file via HTTP, not downloading "in general".  I know people love to view "the web" and "the internet" as being synonymous, but they ain't.  There are all sorts of methods of downloading/uploading files that don't involve clicking links, browsers, HTTP, or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But, I am talking about downloading via HTTPS, HTTP, FTP and most other downloading methods. If it is a file being downloaded to the computer, I want to block it. I think this does count as downloading "in general".

Comment: What about Bit Torrent? SSH? Subversion? All of those would fall under "downloading in general" but good luck trying to block them all with the same method. Note that the two answers you've been given _only_ tell you how to password-protect downloads done over HTTP (or HTTPS).

Comment: Yes, but the two answers given are a starting point. They give me  aplace to start, which is what is needed in 9 out of 10 cases! You talk about Bit Torrent, SSH and Subversion! Note this, and keep it in the back of your mind... If it is computerized, there is always a way to hack it, or block it! I never said I was using one method, one script ( using threading probably ) can use more than one method at a time. So, this brings me back to "downloading in general"!

Comment: If you control the server the file is on, you can control the means that it is downloaded with, including authentication options.  There's no such thing as protection for willy nilly "downloading in general"

Comment: So far, there is. I am almost done with the script! It prevents downloading of certain extensions (.exe, .mp3, .mp4, etc) just like I said. It doesn't matter what method is used to download ( FTP, HTTP, HTTPS, etc), it still blocks the download! So, I guess this either means I invented "general downloading", or, it does in fact exist!

Comment: @Zachary Brown: "general downloading" doesn't exist.  What piece of software runs your script?  Apache?  If so, you're only protecting WEB-based downloading.  Lots of other servers **could** be running that you're not considering.  Please **UPDATE** your question to name the specific piece of software which is doing the downloading.  If it's Apache, please say "APACHE" in your question.  Please.

Comment: There is no software running my script. I wrote the script, every aspect of it is in Python. Like I said above, it does prevent the downloading of certain files from any other computer, wether in the local networ or on the web, and prompts for a username and password. I thank everyone for thier input, and for this rivetting conversation.

Comment: @Zachary Brown: What protocol do this "script" implement?  Files cannot be downloaded without some communications protocol.  Please update the question with the **specific** protocol you've implemented.  Please provide us some facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTTP's [basic authentication](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml) (shown in the URL I've quoted from the client side):

1. whenever a "sensitive" page or file is requested, and no Authorization header is part
   of the request (or it's invalid, see below), return a 401 status code instead,
   with a header `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=XXXX` (where XXXX is a hash of the URL,
   e.g. with MD5 or SHA1, to make it essentially unique per-file)
2. the user will then need to enter username and password at his browser, which will
   send them back to the server you're implementing with the simple algorithm shown
   at that URL, namely:

   import base64
   base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password))[:-1]
   req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
3. when the Authorization header is present in the request, decode the base64 string
   it presents after `'Basic '` and check that it has the `username:password` you want

You can use more sophisticated authentication, of course, but this may get you started unless the user's connection can (or so you suspect) be "sniffed" by evil third parties (in which case you'll want to use HTTPS anyway, so that basic auth becomes OK again;-).

Comment: "decode the base53 string it presents" you mean the base64 string?

Comment: @Techno, oops, yes, off-by-one typo from fast typing w/wrong parallax, fixing now, tx!-)

Comment: Just trying to prove you are not a bot, eh :)

Comment: @gnibbler, darn, you caught my new subtle masking strategy, I'll have to reset and try a new one!

Answer (score 2):

This is best implemented at the web server level.

If you are using Apache, this can be done by placing the files you desire to protect in a directory with an `htaccess` file which requires user authentication.

Then, implement HTTP Basic Auth in your Python script to download the files.  Make sure to use an SSL connection; basic auth sends the user's password over the wire in the clear.

Comment: Without the trick of the ever-changing realm as per my answer below, the user will need to enter their credentials only once, then their browser will remember and automatically resend them -- that does not seem to match the OP's specs.  (I don't know enough Apache black magic to know if the ever-changing realm can be implemented there easily -- if so, seems an issue for serverfault.com anyway;-).